# Why do fields of different instances mix up in python modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

consider the following python test.py module:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, str_list=[]):
        self.str_list = str_list

    def from_strings(self, st=""):
        self.str_list.append(st)
        return self

o1 = Container().from_strings(st="o1")
o2 = Container().from_strings(st="o2")
o3 = Container().from_strings(st="o3")

def prnt():
    print("o1's list:"+str(o1.str_list))
    print("o2's list:"+str(o2.str_list))
    print("o3's list:"+str(o3.str_list))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prnt()
```

Why is the output of `python test.py`:

```
  o1's list:['o1', 'o2', 'o3']
  o2's list:['o1', 'o2', 'o3']
  o3's list:['o1', 'o2', 'o3']
```

instead of:

```
  o1's list:['o1']
  o2's list:['o2']
  o3's list:['o3']
```

(It seems like I am missing why a field (str_list) of different instances in the same module could mix up.  A pointer to the python doc explaining this concept would be highly appreciated)

Comment: Ah, the old mutable default arg.  This is something you will just have to learn about Python.

Comment: @DSM yes I guess it is along the same lines. I guess it didn't come up in my searches, since I wasn't even suspecting the default argument, but rather thought that the fields mix somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an empty list as default value in your constructor:

```
def __init__(self, str_list=[]):
    self.str_list = str_list
```

This list is only created once and then shared by all instances. If you wanted a separate list for each instance, you could do something like:

```
def __init__(self, str_list=None):
    self.str_list = [] if str_list is None else str_list
```

Now each instance creates it's own list.

**edit:**

### What is going on?

You have probably used default arguments like `1`, or `'foo'` and never had a problem.
These are **immutable** objects which **can not** be manipulated. Whenever you think you do, you get a new instance in stead. The collection of immutable object types includes `int`, `str`, `tuple`, among others.

Now `[]`, a `list`, is a **mutable** object which **can** be manipulated. So whenever you change an attribute on it, it changes the actual object and every reference to it will reflect the changes.

Comment: `self.str_list = str_list or []` can lead to subtle errors - `if str_list is None: str_list = []` is correct